# Reading Range of Lines from a File

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can any one let me know fastest way of showing Range of Lines in a files of 5 GB size. For Example: If the File is having a Size of 5GB and it has line numbers has one of the column in the file. Say if the number of lines in a file are  1 million, I have Start Index Line # and End Index Line #. Say i want to read 25th Line to 89 th line of a large file, rather than reading each and every line, is there any fastest way of reading specific lines from 25th to 89th without reading whole file from begining in C#

Comment: Why do you have line numbers? Do you need the column _line number_ at all or can you count every line?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. How can you possibly know where the carriage returns/line numbers are before you actually read them?

To avoid memory issues you could:

```
File.ReadLines(path)
    .SkipWhile(line=>someCondition)
    .TakeWhile(line=>someOtherCondition)
```

5GB is a huge amount of data to sift through without building some sort of index. I think you've stumbled upon a case where loading your data into a database and adding the appropriate indexes might serve you best.

Comment: OP has a column _line number_ which should be used.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ...ah well, that only compounds the problem, right?

Comment: if we read Line Number from memory Stream of File and we can decide seeking to particular line. does it make sense